# C string comparison

Tags: c, string, loops, while-loop

I ve been coding in C++, completly new in C.
Why doesnt it work? I want to end program by typing exit

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  char command[4];

  do{
          printf( "  -> " ) ;
          scanf("%c", &command);
  }while(&command != "exit");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really should save C-style strings for later. They're really complex and you should get yourself much more comfortable with the language before you tackle them.

Comment: first time I have seen it this way round. Normally a c->c++ programmer getting stuck and we say use std::string. Here a c++->c std::string-using programmer is stuck using c strings

Comment: Short answer: in C, none of the comparison or relational operators are defined to work with array types (and strings are stored as arrays of `char`).  You have to use the `strcmp` or `strncmp` library functions to compare strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in C you have to use `strcmp` for string comparison.

In C a string is a sequence of characters that ends with the `'\0'`-terminating byte, whose value is 0.

The string  `"exit"` looks like this in memory:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| 'e' | 'x' | 'i' | 't' | '\0' |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+

where 'e' == 101, 'x' == 120, etc.
```

The values of the characters are determined by the codes of the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

```
&command != "exit"
```

is just comparing pointers.

```
while(strcmp(command, "exit") != 0);
```

would be correct. `strcmp` returns 0 when both strings are equal, a non-zero
value otherwise. See

> *man strcmp*
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
>
> int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `strcmp()` function  compares  the two strings `s1` and `s2`. It returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if `s1` is
>   found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than `s2`.

But you've made another error:

```
scanf("%c", &command);
```

Here you are reading 1 character only, this `command` is not a string.

```
scanf("%s", command);
```

would be correct.

The next error would be

```
char command[4];
```

This can hold strings with a maximal length of 3 characters, so `"exit"` doesn't
fit in the buffer.

Make it

```
char command[1024];
```

Then you can store a string with max. length of 1023 bytes.

In general, of want to save a string of length `n`, you need a `char` array of
at least `n+1` dimension.

Comment: That continues the loop while the strings are identical, 0 result means same, or "no difference".

Comment: @tadman yes, you are right, I fixed the answer. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: `scanf( "%s", command ) ;` the & is not needed.

Comment: @Clifford thanks for the feedback, I just did copy & paste and changed fro `%c` to `%s` without looking the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp), obviously:

```
while (strcmp(c, "exit"))
```

What your code does is compare the *address* of the input buffer with the address of the static string `"exit"`, which of course will never match. You must compare the characters *at* the pointers.

The orher problem is you have a four byte buffer for a five byte string, the terminator character needs to fit. C is extremely tricky this way, you'll need to allocate a "big enough" buffer for whatever people might type in or the program will immediately crash. Use 1024 or something reasonably big for test programs.

Now I say "obviously" because when writing C code you should have a [C standard library reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) open at all times to be sure you're using the correct functions and arguments, plus to know what tools you have available.

Comment: I’d prefer to see an explicit `!= 0` in the test.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues with the code

1. You need five chars not four to include the ending null char `\0`.
2. You should use `%s` for inputting string. `%c` is for characters
3. You are comparing memory locations (or pointers) in the while loop. You need `strcmp` for comparing strings.